# Mail Client Configuration for each domain on a server

Tags: linux, apache, email, cpanel, whm

We have WHM and cPanel on a linux/apache server.
We are running separate domains on separate ip's on this server. Below is an example:

DOMAIN : IP

```
domain1.com: *.11  
domain2.com: *.12  
domain3.com: *.13
```

Each domain should have it's own mail.

```
mail.domain1.com  
mail.domain2.com  
mail.domain3.com
```

The A Entry for the Hostname is

```
hostname:         web.domain1.com   
server main ip:   *.11
```

The DNS Zone records for domain3.com:

```
The NS record for domain3.com:      ns1.domain1.com  
The NS record for domain3.com:      ns2.domain1.com  
The A  record for domain3.com:      *.13  
The MX record for domain3.com:      mail.domain3.com  
The A  record for mail.domain3.com: *.13
```

The problem is that mail.domain3.com is still using web.domain1.com for it's incoming and outgoing mail.

Is there anyway to get domain3.com to use its own mail.domain3.com instead of pointing to web.domain1.com? (which is also causing some SSL certificate warning for the wrong certificate for domain3.com (domain3.com is using web.domain1.com's SSL cert. when it should be using it's own SSL cert.))

Much thanks in advance! :D

-Tony

Answer (score 0):

Can't set MX as mail.domainname, Set MX as physical name of your server means hostname. You should make entries as:

> The A  record for domain3.com:      *.13
>   The MX record for domain3.com:      Hostname

Don't set mail.domain3.com record.